# Почему возникает предупреждение UserWarning: Parsing '31-12-2022' in DD/MM/YYYY format?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня имеется датафрейм (я прилагаю только один столбец):

```
     Дата_расчетов
0    2020-01-09
1    2020-02-18
2    2020-04-10
3    2020-04-13
4    2020-04-20
5    2020-04-30
6    2020-05-20
7    2020-06-01
8    2020-09-30
9    2020-10-01
10   2020-10-29
Name: Дата расчетов, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Данные собраны из xlsx и html файлов и первоначально имеют тип данных object.

Столбец предварительно отформатирован следующим образом:

```
all_dfs['Дата_расчетов'] = pd.to_datetime(all_dfs['Дата_расчетов'], format='%d.%m.%Y')
```

Когда я выполняю следующий код:

```
year = input()
sell_year = all_sell[(all_sell['Дата расчетов'] >= f'01-01-{year}') & (all_sell['Дата расчетов'] <= f'31-12-{year}')]
```

Получаю предупреждение:

```
c:\Users\User\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\arraylike.py:52: UserWarning: Parsing '31-12-2022' in DD/MM/YYYY format. Provide format or specify infer_datetime_format=True for consistent parsing.
  return self._cmp_method(other, operator.le)
```

Без f-строки предупреждение аналогично.
Как избавиться от данного предупреждения?

Comment: потому что pandas не может догадаться, где у вас день, а где месяц в записи "01-01-2000". Вы же привели фрагмент датафрейма. там же видна нотация - год-месяц-день. ну так и пишите сравнение в такой же нотации.